# How to determine which DLL an Excel UDF is coming from?

Tags: excel, vba, dll, interop, user-defined-functions

is there any way to determine from an Excel session, which DLL an UDF is coming from ?

I have a bunch of DLLs loaded by default, I wanted to determine for every UDF where it was defined.

If the UDF was not defined in a DLL but via VBA, is there a way to determine in which XLA or XLS it was defined ?

Thanks very much for taking some time to read this.

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on Microsoft website.

This VBA macro will return a list of functions, their signature for C/Excel interface and the DLL/XLL from which they were loaded:

```
Function GetDLLList()
  GetDLLList = Application.RegisteredFunctions
End Function
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/108002